# Role is not created with the name I intended

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config()

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('test')
    .setDescription('test')
        .addStringOption((data) => data
           .setName("serverid")
           .setDescription("serverID")
           .setRequired(true))
        .setDMPermission(false),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const user = interaction.user
        const InputServerID = interaction.options.getString("serverid");
        const {client, Server} = interaction

        const TargetServer = await client.guilds.fetch(InputServerID)
        const LogCheckRole = await TargetServer.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: 'LogCheck',
                //color: 'BLUE',
            },
            reason: 'test',
        })
    }
}
```

This is part of my code. The role is created but it doesn't have the name and color I specified. How do I apply roles with the names and colors I intend?

When the command is executed, a blue role named LogCheck should be created on the server you specified.
However, the actually created role has the name new role and no color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of v14, [RoleManager#create()](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create) takes a single argument, containing both the data and reason. The options you provided were invalid, and that is why the created role had all the defaults set.

Also, to apply use a color, you can either pass a `Color` value, RGB tuple, or other `ColorResolvable`.

```js
const { Colors, ... } = require('discord.js');

// ...

const LogCheckRole = await TargetServer.roles.create({
   name: 'LogCheck',
   color: Colors.Blue,
   reason: 'test',
});
```